# How to visualize positions of bodies using Gnuplot from Fortran?

Tags: fortran, gnuplot, simulation, physics, figure

I developed a script that calculates the position of N bodies during a gravitational simulation, and I'd like some tips to visualize it. So far, I can either plot the initial conditions, the final position **or** the trajectories of **all** bodies, which is not so great. My goal now is "simply" to visualize the movement of all the bodies and/or to plot several figures (one for each time increase) such that, later, it may be possible to do a gif with "animate *.png".

So far I managed to call Gnuplot inside my Fortran code like this:

```
call system('gnuplot data_test.plt')
```

Where "data_test.plt" is:

```
set terminal x11
plot 'teste.dat' pt 5 ps 1
pause 0.1
clear
```

And "teste.dat" is a file (re-)created at every time increase, which contains the position (x,y) of all the N bodies at that given time.

Comment: Welcome, please take the welcome [tour]. This site is designed for questions that can be answered ideally with one answer that solves the question.  Not for asking for tips. It would be good if you could ask an actual question in your post. I went ahead and put such a question into the title. Please review it and ideally ask also a question in the main body.

Comment: I guess some previous posts may be a good starting point (e.g., using "for" loops with "index" or "every" etc). https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=gnuplot+animation  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36162214/how-to-animate-multiple-points-planets-using-gnuplot-from-a-single-data-file

Comment: I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31386567/how-to-let-gnuplot-window-persist-and-the-main-program-not-freeze) has some tips that may help you.